# How should I output a string to a text box in c, using windows.h?

Tags: c, windows, text, header, output

I'm making a program in c that uses a gui to help accomplish a task. The program is supposed to increment each character value inputted by the amount in the key. I am having problems with this however, I can't figure out how to debug it properly, because I can't really output text to the screen at certain points of the code. My problem though seems to be that I'm not quite sure how to accomplish outputting text to a text box with windows.h. Can anyone figure it out?

EDIT: I figured out that the problem is that the event switch is not activating on WM_COMMAND. Due to my lack of knowledge with windows.h, I cannot figure out what exactly is wrong with either the button or the switch. Any guesses?

```
#include <windows.h>

int inRange(int min, int max, int val) {
    if (val >= min) {
        if (val <= max) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
}

int cypher(int x, int y) {
    if (!(inRange('A','Z',x) == 0)) {
        if (!(inRange('a','z',x) == 0)) {
            return x;
        }
    }
    int dec;
    int a = x;
    int b = y;
    if (inRange('A','Z',x) == 0) {
        dec = 0;
    }
    else {
        dec = 1;
    }
    a = b + a;
    hyperloop:
    if (inRange('A','Z',a) == -1) {
        a = a + 26;
    }
    else if (inRange('A','Z', a) == 1) {
        if (inRange('a','z', a) == -1) {
            if (dec == 0) {
                a = a - 26;
            }
            else {
                a = a + 26;
            }
        }
        else if (inRange('a','z', a) == 1) {
            a = a - 26;
        }
    }
    if (!(inRange('A','Z',a) == 0)) {
        if (!(inRange('a','z',a))== 0) {
            goto hyperloop;
        }
    }
    return a;
}

int strtoint(char integer[7]) {
    int count;
    int counter;
    int countval;
    int polarity;
    int res = 0;
    int raw[7] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    if (integer[0] == '-') {
        polarity = -1;
        countval = 1;
    }
    else {
        polarity = 1;
        countval = 0;
    }
    raw[0] = polarity;
    for (count = countval; count <= 6; count = count + 1) {
        if (integer[count] == 0) {
            break;
        }
        for (counter = 1; counter <= 6; counter = counter + 1) {
            raw[counter] = raw[counter] * 10;
        }
        raw[count - countval + 1] = integer[count] - '0';
    }
    for (count = 1; count <= 6; count = count + 1) {
        res = res + raw[count];
    }
    res = res * polarity;
    return res;

}

HWND maintext, button, cypherbox, keybox, outbox;
char raw[100], clean[100];
char keyraw[7];
int cyphercontent, keycontent;
char pointers[5];
int devoid;
int key;
int count;
char test[] = {'T','e','s','t','\0'};

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM 
lParam) {

    switch(Message) {

        /* Upon destruction, tell the main thread to stop */
        case WM_CREATE: {
            maintext = CreateWindow("STATIC",
            "Input a cypher and a key (up to 100 characters cypher)\n",
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
            20, 20, 960, 200,
            hwnd,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            NULL);

            button = CreateWindow("BUTTON",
            "OK",
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
            20,
            85,
            25,
            18,
            maintext,
            (HMENU) 1,
            NULL,
            NULL);

            cypherbox = CreateWindow("EDIT",
            "text here",
            WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
            20,
            25,
            920,
            20,
            maintext,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            NULL);


            keybox = CreateWindow("EDIT",
            "keyhere",
            WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
            20,
            45,
            57,
            20,
            maintext,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            NULL);

            outbox = CreateWindow("STATIC",
            clean,
            WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
            20,
            105,
            920,
            20,
            maintext,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            NULL);

            break;
        }
        case WM_COMMAND: {

            switch (LOWORD(wParam)) {
                case 1: {
                    //clear raw and clean
                    for (count = 0; count <100; count = count + 1) {
                        raw[count] = 0;
                        clean[count] = 0;
                    }
                    for (count = 0; count < 6; count = count + 1) {
                        keyraw[count] = 0;
                    }
                    //things that I didn't need to do but did anyways
                    cyphercontent = 0;
                    keycontent = 0;
                    pointers[0] = &raw[0];
                    pointers[1] = &keyraw[0];
                    //obtain text from both boxes
                    cyphercontent = GetWindowText(
                    cypherbox,
                    pointers[0],
                    100
                    );
                    keycontent = GetWindowText(
                    keybox,
                    pointers[1],
                    7
                    );
                    //convert the string input to number output
                    key = strtoint(keyraw);
                    for (count = 0; count <= 99; count = count + 1) {
                        clean[count] = cypher(raw[count],key);
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }

            break;
        }
        case WM_DESTROY: {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        }

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, Message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    WNDCLASSEX wc; /* A properties struct of our window */
    HWND hwnd; /* A 'HANDLE', hence the H, or a pointer to our window */
    MSG msg; /* A temporary location for all messages */

    /* zero out the struct and set the stuff we want to modify */
    memset(&wc,0,sizeof(wc));
    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc; /* This is where we will send messages to */
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);

    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wc.lpszClassName = "WindowClass";
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, "cypher_text.ico"); 
    wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, "cypher_text.ico"); 

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Registration 
Failed!","Error!",MB_ICONEXCLAMATION|MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        "WindowClass",
        "Cypher.exe",
        WS_VISIBLE|WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, /* x */
        CW_USEDEFAULT, /* y */
        1020, /* width */
        280, /* height */
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL);

    if(hwnd == NULL) {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Creation 
Failed!","Error!",MB_ICONEXCLAMATION|MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) { 
        TranslateMessage(&msg); 
        DispatchMessage(&msg); 
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: Open your program with the console and write to `stderr`, or you can use the logging system of windows and watch the logs

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SetWindowText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633546(v=vs.85).aspx) to set the text in a textbox. Example:

```
SetWindowText(outbox, "Hello World!");
```